What is this plaster scoring technique called?
Recently inherited a home after my grandfather’s passing. The home has some unique features, one of which is this brick-like scoring into the plaster in the restroom and kitchen. He told me the name of the style, but I can’t remember. I personally don’t care for the way it looks, but he seemed to think it was special. Thanks in advance. It was built in 1937, but this was done wayyyy later, I’m sure.


I have heard that called "Bricking".  I believe there are other names as well

With that vertical joint there, it may be applied panels, not plaster. Plaster would not need a continuous  vertical joint. If the plasterers can make the brick pattern in the rest of the wall, why would they do that there? They could have as easily done it without the continuous joint.
